# how to resolve the stack overflow error showing by the following code?

Tags: string, recursion, data-structures, stack-overflow

while running this code

```
//Question: print all binary string of size n without consecutive one's

import java.util.*;
public class BinaryString {
    
    public static void binaryString(int n , int lastPlace , String str)
    {
        if(n==0)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        binaryString(n-1,0,str + "0");
        if(lastPlace==0)
        {
            binaryString(n-1,1,str+ "1");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter value of n: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        binaryString(n,0," ");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

the following error is showing , how to resolve this error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(Unsafe.java:1380)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.newArray(StringConcatHelper.java:441)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:365)
        at BinaryString.binaryString(BinaryString.java:10)
```

it should print the binary strings.

Comment: `binaryString` *always* calls itself; stop having it do that.

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  Did you read what the `dsa` tag is for?

Comment: You should spend a few minutes single-stepping the code in your debugger to understand why `binaryString` always calls itself. Don't know how to use the debugger? Now is the perfect time to learn!